# link to selection of option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in contact page and three links suppose one, two, and three are in home page and I would like to link to contact page for each link but with one option is to be selected one and with two option is to be selected two and so on.

```
<select id="message_type" name="message_type" class="inputbox">
    <option value="one">Suggestion</option>
    <option value="two">Inquiry</option>
    <option value="three">Offer</option>
</select>
```

when link one is clicked the contact page should show option selected one and the like.

How can I do that?

---

**Edit**

I have three links in home page

```
<a href="contact.php" id="one">one</a>
<a href="contact.php" id="two">two</a>
<a href="contact.php" id="three">three</a>
```

Now I want to show the contact page with option selected one for link one and so on...

---

here is the code which results the select

```
<?php 
function dropdown($active){
$dropdown=array(
                'option1'=>'Suggestion','option2'=>'Inquiry','option3'=>'Offers'
                );

foreach($dropdown as $key=>$val){
$array[]=JHtml::_('select.option',$val,$key);
}
$dropdown  = JHtml::_('select.genericlist',$array,'message_type','class="inputbox"','text','value',$active);
return $dropdown;
}
?>
```

and in the form

```
<form name="feedback" id="frmfeedback" action=""  method="post" >
<div>
<label for="msg">Message Type: </label><span class="input"><?php echo dropdown(isset($post['message_type'])?$post['message_type']:'');?> </span>
</div>
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can put a hash in the links on home page:

```
<a href="contact.html#one">Make a Suggestion</a>
```

Then on contact page:

```
$(function(){
    var opts=['one','two','three'];
    var hash =location.hash;// use browser location object to get hash
    if(hash && hash !='#'){
      hash= hash.replace('#','');
      /* get index of hash from array*/
      var optIndex= $.inArray(hash,opts);
       /* if not in array value will be empty string, otherwise value of hash*/
      $('#message_type').val( optIndx !=-1 ? hash : '' );
    }
});
```

EDIT: If ID's are same as values on the links as shown in question

Can append the hashes to href on home page with:

```
$('#one,#two,#three').attr('href',function(idx, oldHref){
     return oldHref +'#' + this.id;
});
```

EDIT: Using `itemId` in query string of url:

```
$(function(){
     var opts=['477','478','479']; /* not sure these are accurate*/
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = location.href;
    var ret = {},
        seg = a.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&'),
        len = seg.length,
        i = 0,
        s;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (!seg[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        s = seg[i].split('=');
        ret[s[0]] = s[1];
    }
    var currVal=ret['itemId'];
    if( currVal !=undefined && $.inArray(currVal,opts)>-i){
        $('#message_type').val( currVal);
    }

})
```

Comment: joomla shouldn't care about the hash... is most common way of linking to anchors within a page

Comment: unless you mean you have no way of adding the hash from admin

Comment: I found id are different like this..... index.php?option=com_contact&view=category&id=79&Itemid=477               index.php?option=com_contact&view=category&id=79&Itemid=478

Comment: OK ...not hard to parse the ItemID from the query string.... can you change the values of the `<option>` tags to match?

Comment: I decided to use by adding a hash coz if SEO enabled then the the url will be changed.

Comment: makes sense... I added query method also

Comment: Thank you so much... but I'm unable to use hash something wrong?....   $('#header-menu .moduletable:last-child .menu a').attr('href',function(idx, oldHref){
     return oldHref +'#' + this.id;
});

Comment: could use `$("a:contains(Suggestion)").attr` and do a line for each as worst case

Comment: I've managed to show the hashes #option1, #option2, and #optin3 but not option is selected when clicked to the link

Comment: does opts array match hashes and values in option tags? And are hashes showing in url when switch page?

Comment: have a live page link?

Comment: http://nepotech.com/kldugar/     under search box three imgs are there which goes to contact page.

Comment: I found it.....you commented some of it out. I tested it in console and it works except I left a typo in `optIndx`  missing `e` should be optIndex

Comment: Or is it because the options are resulted from php?

Comment: HI! I noticed here is wrong $('#message_type').val( option2 ) that is optIndx !=-1 ? hash : '' producing without " " So I need to convert to tosring how to do?

Comment: hash is a string. I tested the code that was in your file in console while on page and it worked fine...it was just commented out in your file

Answer (score 0):

For different pages

```
var url= document.URL;
switch(url)
{
    case 'http://jsfiddle.net/bs8dp/':
        $('#message_type').val('one');
        break;

     case 'http://jsfiddle.net/bs66p/':
        $('#message_type').val('one');
        break;

     default:
           $('#message_type').val('two');



}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs8dp/2/)

OR

If you have options in same page then

```
('#your_tab_one').click(function(){

   $('#message_type').val('one');

});

('#your_tab_two').click(function(){

   $('#message_type').val('two');

});

('#your_tab_three').click(function(){

   $('#message_type').val('three');

});
```

Comment: you can change the url to a variable thats changing in different conditions